# Dash compatibility and the ECU

Tags: citroen, electronic-control-module

I have a Citroen C1 and it's a very basic model. It doesn't have a rev counter but I can add one because it has the cable and plug for it already exists, it's just not plugged into a rev counter.
What I was wondering is, does anyone know if the plugs that feed the dashboard to provide speed, fuel level, mileage and warning lights fit in other dashboards? Basically, are the plugs standardized?

And, do all ECU's calculate MPG and just not display it on the dash or do they not calculate it and it's just specific ECU's?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about your Citroen in particular, but all cars are made differently. Some have what you are asking about and some don't. It is all in how the manufacturer designs and sets them up. A usual rule of thumb here is the more expensive the car, the more gadgets you'll find.

One of the ways you can figure out if you might be able to add other gauges and such is, check to see is if there is another version of your C1 which *does* have the things you are looking for. If there is one, you could most possibly have it added to yours. To save manufacturing/design costs, manufacturers will use the same wiring harness and ECU over many different models and option packages of models. Changes to the vehicles are made right on the assembly line where a build sheet will tell the person which parts to add (low end gauge set or high end gauge set). They don't have to worry about the other components at this point because they are already in place.